# Error Occurred Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, sql

## looking at countries with highest infection rate compare to population

```
select coviddeaths.location,
       date,
       population,
       max(total_cases) HighestInfectionCount,
       max((total_cases/population))*100 PercentPopulationInfected
from coviddeaths
Group by location, population
order by PercentPopulationInfected;
```

#[42000][1055] Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'portfolioproject.coviddeaths.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: The error is pretty clear, and similar questions are (still) asked a lot, what about the answers to those didn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Date field to your Group By statement should work.

```
SELECT
    LOCATION,
    DATE,
    POPULATION,
    MAX(TOTAL_CASES) AS 'HIGHESTINFECTIONCOUNT',
    MAX((TOTAL_CASES/POPULATION)) * 100 AS 'PERCENTPOPULATIONINFECTED'
FROM COVIDDEATHS
GROUP BY
    LOCATION,
    DATE,
    POPULATION
ORDER BY 5
```